# Tensorflow custom gradients don't backpropagate

Tags: python, tensorflow, backpropagation

I'm trying to understand custom gradients in tensorflow with `tf.custom_gradient`, so I was trying to reproduce a simple matrix multiplication with its gradients, where I'm only interested with the gradient with respect to the weight matrix.

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def matrixmul(x, weight):
    res = tf.matmul(x, weight)

    def grad(dy):
        grad_x = None
        grad_w = tf.matmul(x, dy, transpose_a=True)
        return grad_x, grad_w

    return res, grad
```

This gives the right gradient whenever I don't my custom gradient is not used in the backpropagation, but when I do multiple multiplications the gradient doesn't propagate back and I get `None` as a result for `grad_w1`.

For example:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    temp = matrixmul(x, w1)
    pred = tf.matmul(temp, w2)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.norm(pred - y, axis=-1))
grad_w1 = tape.gradient(loss, w1)
```

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    temp = tf.matmul(x, w1)
    pred = matrixmul(temp, w2)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.norm(pred - y, axis=-1))
grad_w1 = tape.gradient(loss, w1)
```

The first snippet gives the right gradients, but the second snippet results in `None`.

Comment: As you point out, your custom gradient does not compute the gradient for the first parameter of the matrix multiplication. That means that, from the point of view of TensorFlow, the function is not differentiable with respect to `x`. In the second snippet, the backpropagation ends therefore at `temp`, and it never reaches `w1`.

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed. Is there a way to avoid the need to implement a gradient with respect to `x`?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The computation of the gradient works in a chain, if you have a sequence of operations like `x1 = f1(x0); x2 = f2(x1); x3 = f3(x2)`, the gradient of `x3` wrt `x0` would be `f3'(x2) * f2'(x1) * f1'(x0)`, so all of `f1'`, `f2'` and `f3'` need to be defined.